# Unable to connect python script in PowerBI

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I have imported data into PowerBI, I am now trying to execute some python scripting on the imported data, but I get the above error.
Please note that I have installed both numpy and pandas through the pip install function in cmd.

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVQQL.jpg)

Comment: What do your Python settings look like in Power BI? Is your home directory correctly set, for instance?

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: you may have common problem - you may have two Pythons. You installed `pandas` in one Python but code runs other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. maybe in code check `print( sys.executable )` to get `C:\full\path\to\python.exe` and use `C:\full\path\to\python.exe -m pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That isn’t a valid Python home directory path. Try browsing to a folder where Python is installed.

I can think of 2 possibilities of you getting the above error, either you haven’t installed Python in your C Drive, or you are trying to browse the path from Start Menu and copying the same path in the directory which will eventually give the above error as that’s not the exact path of your python.

Try to locate the folder in your respective directory where you have downloaded the python with a naming convention of Python39 or Python310 (based on your Python version) as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check whether the below steps were followed:
Click on File --> Options and settings --> Options --> Under GLOBAL section click on Python scripting --> Check the Detected Python home directories is whether Python 39 or Python310 (based on your Python version).
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Du4F.png)

Make sure that the Detected Python home directory is not of Anaconda.

Secondly, change your Detected Python IDEs from “Default OS program for .PY files” to “Other” and browse the suitable IDE of your choice.

I would recommend choosing Microsoft VS Code as I have chosen the same.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNPU5.png)

Now let me show you the working.

Click on Get Data --> More.. -->Type Python Script in Search --> Select “Python Script” --> Click on “Connect”.
Now type the below code in the script in order to load the data. (Make sure you have given your own data path). Next click on “OK”.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZO8h.png)

A Navigator window will be opened as shown below. Select the data required by you and click on “Load”.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMRmu.png)

I hope my detailed answer will help you, for any further issues please feel free to reply.
Contributors from KLH:
2010030470,2010030119,2010030088,2010030155

Comment: @19671698,
I am unable to find the respective directory of python in my Detected Python Home Directories, as it was showing for you in the given answer, so I have selected “other” option and browsed my Python directory but now it is showing me an error even after setting up the right directory path of python

Comment: @19671698, Error message : “That isn’t a valid Python home directory path. Try browsing to a folder where Python is installed.”